# Can't start activity from a status bar notification defined in library

Tags: android

I build a service into a library, the service will call `setForeground` to make itself appear on status bar.

Then I added this service libary into another *app*, when the *app* starts up the service, it will pass its activity name (e.g.: **com.example.abcd.main**) as a `String` to the service.

I hope when user clicks notification on status bar, it could launch the *app*'s `Acitivity`.
So as to the intent in `PendingIntent` of the service's `setForeground`, I set it as following: `intent.setAction("com.example.abcd.main")`

But the `Activity` didn't start as desired when user clicks the notification.
I have declared the `Acitivty` in the manifest and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch an explicit Activity given its *class name*, you need to use [`setClassName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29), not `setAction()`.

> The primary pieces of information in an intent are:
>
> - **action** -- The general action to be performed, such as ACTION_VIEW, ACTION_EDIT, ACTION_MAIN, etc.
> - **data** -- The data to operate on, such as a person record in the contacts database, expressed as a Uri.
>
> (...)
>
> In addition to these primary attributes, there are a number of
>   secondary attributes that you can also include with an intent:
>
> - **component** -- Specifies an explicit name of a component class to use for the intent. Normally this is determined by looking at the other
>     information in the intent (the action, data/type, and categories) and
>     matching that with a component that can handle it. If this attribute
>     is set then none of the evaluation is performed, and this component is
>     used exactly as is. By specifying this attribute, all of the other
>     Intent attributes become optional.

However, wouldn't it be simpler to just pass the `Class<?>` reference itself, or even the full Intent, to the service? (Intents are Parcelable, so they can be sent as extras of another Intent if you're starting the service with a start command).

Comment: what you said is right, however, we still could use setaction to call for an activity. I figured out the reason it failed was because the activity should be marked with "<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />"